# Control reaches end of non-void functionclang(-Wreturn-type

Tags: c++, vector

```
long getMinCost(vector<int> crew_id, vector<int> job_id) 
{
        
    for(int i=1; i < crew_id.size(); i++){
   cout << crew_id[i] << ' ';
    }
}`
```

Control reaches end of non-void functionclang(-Wreturn-type

Comment: You need to add a return statement to your function.  You declare it to return a long, yet return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The function signature:

```
long getMinCost(blah, blah)
```

means your function should return a `long`.

So, either *return* a `long`, or change the signature so you don't nave to return anything:

```
void getMinCost(blah, blah)
```

Given the function name, `getMinCost`, I suspect you *should* be returning something. You just need to figure out what (neither a crew ID nor a job ID would seem to be obvious candidates for a minimum cost).